# SMB Share Through the Web

Tags: windows, web, server-message-block

I'm looking to setup an SMB/windows share that you can access through the internet on either a windows 2003 or windows 2008 server. This would be for a server behind a firewall, I have a handle on NAT. I'm mainly looking for a tool that can setup which share that needs to be shared publicly and authentication. I got the idea from the \live.sysinternals.com\tools site (read [here](http://www.edbott.com/weblog/2008/05/working-with-sysinternals-live/)).

I've seen lots of posts here and on google about setting up a *web based* SMB share, but I'm looking more to setup a full \sharename.domain.com access back to the server (read only of course), so I can map to it from a remote location.

Can this be done with native tools, or would I need a 3rd party app?

Comment: you could use webdav and map that if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tony roth pointed out. webdav did the trick for me. They key here was needing to install the update for it found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=17C36612-632E-4C04-9382-987622ED1D64&displaylang=en) to get it working on my windows 7 machine. After that I was actually able to map web sites to drive letters `net use z: https://share.domain.com` , wasn't exactly what I was asking for, but this did exactly what I needed it for.

Answer (score 0):

Simply forwarding the port tcp/139 and/or tcp/445 from your NAT device to the destination server maybe after setting [DisableStrictNameChecking](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308) would do that. Although you would potentially (if you have a username with enough access rights and the corresponding password handy) get access to all shares on the destination server, Windows does not support any kind of per-interface or per-client restriction for share access controls.